# Add-in for Outlook giving error ""Configuration system failed to initialize"

Tags: outlook-addin

I am migrating a working outlook add-in to run on outlook 2013 and getting the error ""Configuration system failed to initialize".

The app.config file is fine as the add-in loads and works when I am trying to run it from the visual studio 2010. However, when I create the deployment msi (created using WiX and ms bootstrapper) and installed it on the development machine it did not work.

On inspection I found that no user.profile is created in the c:\users\\AppData\Local... folder. So I have a hunch that something is stopping the add-in from creating this file. However, I am also writing a log file from the add-in and that seems to be creating fine.

My dll.manifest file has:

```
<trustInfo>
    <security>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">        
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

Am I missing something?

Any clues? Thanks for your time.